# Save cropped image into data base as an physical file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Can any one help on this ?

here i'm using and crop option which for user avtar which replicats on same place but now what i need is to save that new uploaded image into data base as an physical file,
is there any possible way to save it in input field or by ajax call?
or any other ways.......

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>My Profile</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
      <section>
<!-- Upload image -->
<div id="sectionDragAndDrop">
    <div class="cotainer-fluid ediProfile">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row editprofile_nav ">
              <div class="col-md-2 col-2"><a href="homepage.html">
                  <img src="../img/svg/back_ico.svg" width="auto" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 col-10 text-start px-0">
                  <h4 class="text-danger">EDIT PROFILE</h4>
              </div>           
          </div>
          <form action="" method="post">
          <div class="row ediProfile_avtar d-flex_l">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-6 text-start ">
              <p>Avatar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-5 text-end image-upload">
              
                <div class="drop" id="drop">
                    <img src="../img/svg/Group 15.svg"/>
                    
                </div>
                <input class="file-upload hidden" id="fileUpload" type="file">
          </div>
  
            <div class="col-md-1 col-1 d-flex_l">
              <a class="drop" >
              <img src="../img/svg/Stroke 1.svg" alt="">
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>
          <div class="row ediProfile_avtar d-flex_l">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-4 text-start ">
              <p>Nickname<p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-7 text-end">
             <p>0987654321</p>     
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-1 ">
              <img src="../img/svg/Stroke 1.svg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</div>

<!-- Resize image -->
<div class="hidden" id="sectionResize">
    <div class="cotainer-fluid ediProfileImage">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row editprofileImage_nav d-flex_l mt-4">
              <div class="col-md-2 col-2"><a href="index.html">
                  <img src="../img/svg/Group 2.svg" width="auto" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 col-10 text-end ">
                  <h5 class="crop-select" id="crop">Select Photo</h5>

              </div>           
          </div>
         
          <div class="image-resize mt-4" id="imageResize"></div>

          
           
        
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Insert thumbnail -->

<div class="hidden" id="sectionThumbnail">
  <div class="cotainer-fluid ediProfile">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row editprofile_nav ">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-2"><a href="index.html">
              <img src="../img/svg/back_ico.svg" width="auto" alt=""></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10 col-10 text-start px-0">
              <h4 class="text-danger">EDIT PROFILE</h4>
          </div>           
      </div>
      <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="row ediProfile_avtar d-flex_l">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-6 text-start ">
          <p>Avatar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-5 text-end image-upload">
          
           
              <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail">
             
              </div> 
          
      </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-1 d-flex_l">
          <a class="drop" >
          <img src="../img/svg/Stroke 1.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row ediProfile_avtar d-flex_l">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-4 text-start ">
          <p>Nickname<p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-7 text-end">
         <p>0987654321</p>     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-1 ">
          <img src="../img/svg/Stroke 1.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- 
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail"></div>
  </div>  -->


  
</div>
</section>   
<!-- <script src="../js/app.js"></script> -->
<script>
  // crop

$("#drop").on("click", function () {
    $("#fileUpload").trigger("click");
  });
  
  $("#fileUpload").on("change", function (e) {
    addImage(e.target);
  });
  
  $("#drop").on("dragover", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass("dragging");
  });
  
  $("#drop").on("dragleave", function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("dragging");
  });
  
  $("#drop").on("drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var data = e.dataTransfer || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    addImage(data);
  });
  
  function addImage(data) {
    var file = data.files[0];
    if (file.type.indexOf("image") === -1) {
      alert("Sorry, the file you uploaded doesn't appear to be an image.");
      return false;
    }
  
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
        if (img.width < 200 || img.height < 200) {
          alert(
            "Sorry, the image you uploaded doesn't appear to be large enough."
          );
          return false;
        }
        cropImage(img);
      };
      img.src = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  
  function cropImage(originalImage) {
    $(originalImage).attr("id", "fullImage");
    $("#imageResize").html(originalImage);
    $("#sectionDragAndDrop").addClass("hidden");
    $("#sectionResize").removeClass("hidden");
  
    var newImage = new imageCrop("#fullImage", 200, 200);
  
    $("#crop").on("click", function () {
      var results = newImage.crop();
      $("#thumbnail").html(results.img);
      $("#sectionResize").addClass("hidden");
      $("#sectionThumbnail").removeClass("hidden");
    });
  }
  
  /* FROM OTHER CODEPEN */
  var imageCrop = function (imageTarget, requiredWidth, requiredHeight) {
    // Variables
    var $doc = $(document),
      $cropMarker,
      $originalImage,
      origSrc = new Image(),
      imageTarget = $(imageTarget).get(0),
      imageScale,
      imageRatio,
      cropRatio,
      adjustedRequiredWidth,
      adjustedRequiredHeight,
      eventState = {},
      allowResize = true,
      keyboardMove = false,
      imageLoaded = new $.Deferred();
  
    origSrc.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  
    function init() {
      origSrc.onload = function () {
        // Check to make sure the target image is large enough
        if (origSrc.width < requiredWidth || origSrc.height < requiredHeight) {
          console.log(
            "Image Crop error: The required dimensions are larger than the target image."
          );
          return false;
        }
  
        // And neccessary html
        $(imageTarget)
          .wrap('<div class="ic-container"></div>')
          .before(
            '\
                  <div class="ic-overlay-n" id="icOverlayN"></div>\
                  <div class="ic-overlay-e" id="icOverlayE"></div>\
                  <div class="ic-overlay-s" id="icOverlayS"></div>\
                  <div class="ic-overlay-w" id="icOverlayW"></div>\
                  <div class="ic-crop-marker" id="icCropMarker">\
                      <div class="ic-resize-handle-nw" id="icResizeHandleNW"></div>\
                      <div class="ic-resize-handle-ne" id="icResizeHandleNE"></div>\
                      <div class="ic-resize-handle-sw" id="icResizeHandleSW"></div>\
                      <div class="ic-resize-handle-se" id="icResizeHandleSE"></div>\
                      <div class="ic-move-handle" id="icMoveHandle"></div>\
                  </div>\
              '
          );
        $cropMarker = $("#icCropMarker");
        $originalImage = $(imageTarget);
        imageScale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
        imageRatio = origSrc.width / origSrc.height;
        cropRatio = requiredWidth / requiredHeight;
        adjustedRequiredWidth = requiredWidth / imageScale;
        adjustedRequiredHeight = requiredHeight / imageScale;
  
        centerCropMarker();
        repositionOverlay();
  
        $cropMarker.on("mousedown touchstart", startResize);
        $cropMarker.on("mousedown touchstart", "#icMoveHandle", startMoving);
        imageLoaded.resolve();
      };
      origSrc.src = imageTarget.src;
    }
  
    function startResize(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      saveEventState(e);
      $doc.on("mousemove touchmove", resizing);
      $doc.on("mouseup touchend", endResize);
    }
  
    function endResize(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $doc.off("mouseup touchend", endResize);
      $doc.off("mousemove touchmove", resizing);
    }
  
    function resizing(e) {
      var mouse = {},
        width,
        height,
        left,
        top,
        originalWidth = $cropMarker.outerWidth(),
        originalHeight = $cropMarker.outerHeight(),
        originalOffset = $cropMarker.position();
      mouse.x =
        (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) +
        $(window).scrollLeft();
      mouse.y =
        (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) +
        $(window).scrollTop();
  
      var SE = false,
        SW = false,
        NW = false,
        NE = false;
  
      if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is("#icResizeHandleSE")) {
        SE = true;
      } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is("#icResizeHandleSW")) {
        SW = true;
      } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is("#icResizeHandleNW")) {
        NW = true;
      } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is("#icResizeHandleNE")) {
        NE = true;
      }
  
      if (SE) {
        width = mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left;
        height = (width / requiredWidth) * requiredHeight;
        left = eventState.containerLeft;
        top = eventState.containerTop;
      } else if (SW) {
        width =
          eventState.containerWidth -
          (mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left);
        height = (width / requiredWidth) * requiredHeight;
        left = mouse.x - $originalImage.offset().left;
        top = eventState.containerTop;
      } else if (NW) {
        width =
          eventState.containerWidth -
          (mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left);
        height = (width / requiredWidth) * requiredHeight;
        left = mouse.x - $originalImage.offset().left;
        top = originalOffset.top + originalHeight - height;
      } else if (NE) {
        width = mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left;
        height = (width / requiredWidth) * requiredHeight;
        left = eventState.containerLeft;
        top = originalOffset.top + originalHeight - height;
      }
  
      if (
        top >= 0 &&
        left >= 0 &&
        Math.round(top + height) <= Math.round($originalImage.height()) &&
        Math.round(left + width) <= Math.round($originalImage.width())
      ) {
        allowResize = true;
      }
  
      if (allowResize) {
        // Over top boundary
        if (top < 0) {
          height = originalHeight + originalOffset.top;
          width = (height / requiredHeight) * requiredWidth;
          top = 0;
          if (NW) {
            left = originalOffset.left - (width - originalWidth);
          }
          allowResize = false;
        }
        // Over left boundary
        else if (left < 0) {
          width = originalWidth + originalOffset.left;
          height = (width / requiredWidth) * requiredHeight;
          left = 0;
          if (SE) {
            top = originalOffset.top - (height - originalHeight);
          }
          allowResize = false;
        }
        // Over bottom boundary
        else if (Math.round(top + height) > Math.round($originalImage.height())) {
          height = $originalImage.height() - top;
          width = (height / requiredHeight) * requiredWidth;
          if (SW) {
            left = originalOffset.left - (width - originalWidth);
          }
          allowResize = false;
        }
        // Over right boundary
        else if (Math.round(left + width) > Math.round($originalImage.width())) {
          width = $originalImage.width() - left;
          height = (width / requiredWidth) * requiredHeight;
          if (NE) {
            top = originalOffset.top - (height - originalHeight);
          }
          allowResize = false;
        }
  
        // Check for min width / height
        if (width > adjustedRequiredWidth && height > adjustedRequiredHeight) {
          $cropMarker.outerWidth(width).outerHeight(height);
          $cropMarker.css({
            left: left,
            top: top
          });
        } else {
          if (SW || NW) {
            left = left - (adjustedRequiredWidth - width);
          }
          if (NW || NE) {
            top = top - (adjustedRequiredHeight - height);
          }
          $cropMarker
            .outerWidth(adjustedRequiredWidth)
            .outerHeight(adjustedRequiredHeight);
          $cropMarker.css({
            left: left,
            top: top
          });
        }
      }
      repositionOverlay();
    }
  
    function startMoving(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      saveEventState(e);
      $doc.on("mousemove touchmove", moving);
      $doc.on("mouseup touchend", endMoving);
    }
  
    function endMoving(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $doc.off("mouseup touchend", endMoving);
      $doc.off("mousemove touchmove", moving);
    }
  
    function moving(e) {
      var top,
        left,
        mouse = {},
        touches;
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
  
      touches = e.originalEvent.touches;
  
      mouse.x =
        (e.clientX || e.pageX || touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft();
      mouse.y =
        (e.clientY || e.pageY || touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();
  
      top = mouse.y - (eventState.mouseY - eventState.containerTop);
      left = mouse.x - (eventState.mouseX - eventState.containerLeft);
      if (top < 0) {
        top = 0;
      }
      if (top + $cropMarker.outerHeight() > $originalImage.height()) {
        top =
          $originalImage.height() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
      }
      if (left < 0) {
        left = 0;
      }
      if (left + $cropMarker.outerWidth() > $originalImage.width()) {
        left =
          $originalImage.width() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
      }
      $cropMarker.css({
        top: top,
        left: left
      });
      repositionOverlay();
    }
  
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      var top,
        left,
        shiftAmount,
        top = $cropMarker.position().top,
        left = $cropMarker.position().left;
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        shiftAmount = 10;
      } else {
        shiftAmount = 1;
      }
  
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        left = left - shiftAmount;
      } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        top = top - shiftAmount;
      } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        left = left + shiftAmount;
      } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        top = top + shiftAmount;
      }
  
      if (top < 0) {
        top = 0;
      }
      if (top + $cropMarker.outerHeight() > $originalImage.height()) {
        top =
          $originalImage.height() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
      }
      if (left < 0) {
        left = 0;
      }
      if (left + $cropMarker.outerWidth() > $originalImage.width()) {
        left =
          $originalImage.width() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
      }
  
      if (keyboardMove) {
        $cropMarker.css({
          top: top,
          left: left
        });
        repositionOverlay();
      }
    });
  
    $doc.click(function (e) {
      if ($(e.target).closest(".ic-container").length) {
        keyboardMove = true;
      } else {
        keyboardMove = false;
      }
    });
  
    var saveEventState = function (e) {
      eventState.containerWidth = $cropMarker.outerWidth();
      eventState.containerHeight = $cropMarker.outerHeight();
      eventState.containerLeft = $cropMarker.position().left;
      eventState.containerTop = $cropMarker.position().top;
      eventState.mouseX =
        (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) +
        $(window).scrollLeft();
      eventState.mouseY =
        (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) +
        $(window).scrollTop();
      eventState.evnt = e;
    };
  
    var centerCropMarker = function () {
      if (cropRatio > imageRatio) {
        $cropMarker.outerWidth($originalImage.width());
        $cropMarker.outerHeight(
          ($cropMarker.outerWidth() / requiredWidth) * requiredHeight
        );
        $cropMarker.css({
          top: ($originalImage.height() - $cropMarker.height()) / 2 + "px",
          left: 0
        });
      } else {
        $cropMarker.outerHeight($originalImage.height());
        $cropMarker.outerWidth(
          ($cropMarker.outerHeight() / requiredHeight) * requiredWidth
        );
        $cropMarker.css({
          left: ($originalImage.width() - $cropMarker.width()) / 2 + "px",
          top: 0
        });
      }
    };
  
    function repositionOverlay() {
      var imgWidth = $originalImage[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
        imgHeight = $originalImage[0].getBoundingClientRect().height,
        cropTop = $cropMarker.position().top,
        cropLeft = $cropMarker.position().left,
        cropWidth = $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
        cropHeight = $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().height,
        cropBorder = parseFloat($cropMarker.css("border-top-width"));
      $("#icOverlayN").css({
        right: imgWidth - cropLeft - cropWidth,
        height: cropTop,
        left: cropLeft
      });
      $("#icOverlayE").css({
        left: cropLeft + cropWidth
      });
      $("#icOverlayS").css({
        right: imgWidth - cropLeft - cropWidth,
        top: cropTop + cropHeight,
        left: cropLeft
      });
      $("#icOverlayW").css({
        width: cropLeft
      });
    }
  
    // Crop to required size
    this.crop = function () {
      var cropCanvas,
        img = new Image(),
        scale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width(),
        left = Math.round($cropMarker.position().left * scale),
        top = Math.round($cropMarker.position().top * scale),
        width = Math.round($cropMarker.outerWidth() * scale),
        height = Math.round($cropMarker.outerHeight() * scale);
      results;
  
      cropCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      cropCanvas.width = requiredWidth;
      cropCanvas.height = requiredHeight;
      cropCanvas
        .getContext("2d")
        .drawImage(
          origSrc,
          left,
          top,
          width,
          height,
          0,
          0,
          requiredWidth,
          requiredHeight
        );
  
      img.src = cropCanvas.toDataURL();
  
      var results = {
        img: img,
        left: left,
        top: top,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        requiredWidth: requiredWidth,
        requiredHeight: requiredHeight,

      };
      return results;
      
    };
    // dwn.download = 'imagename.png';

    // var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

    // $.ajax({
    //   type: "POST",
    //   url: "script.php",
    //   data: { 
    //      cropCanvas: dataURL
    //   }
    // }).done(function(o) {
    //   console.log('saved'); 
    // });
  
    this.position = function (left, top, width, height) {
      $.when(imageLoaded).done(function () {
        var scale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
        (left = Math.round(left / scale)),
          (top = Math.round(top / scale)),
          (width = Math.round(width / scale)),
          (height = Math.round(height / scale));
        $cropMarker.outerWidth(width).outerHeight(height);
        $cropMarker.css({
          left: left,
          top: top
        });
        repositionOverlay();
      });
    };
  
    this.cropReset = function () {
      centerCropMarker();
      repositionOverlay();
    };
  
    // Viewport resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
      imageScale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
      adjustedRequiredWidth = requiredWidth / imageScale;
      adjustedRequiredHeight = requiredHeight / imageScale;
      centerCropMarker();
      repositionOverlay();
    });
  
    init();
  };
  
  // Initiate Image Crop
  if ($("#exampleImage").length) {
    var exampleCrop = new imageCrop("#exampleImage", 200, 200);
  }
  
  // Crop event
  $("#exampleCrop").on("click", function () {
    var results = exampleCrop.crop();
    $("body").html(results.img);
  });
  
</script>
<!-- <script src="../js/crop.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
</html>
```

Can any one help on this ?

here i'm using and crop option which for user avtar which replicats on same place but now what i need is to save that new uploaded image into data base as an physical file,
is there any possible way to save it in input field or by ajax call?
or any other ways.......